# Performance testing of Kafka Streaming Application

Tags: java, performance, stream, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have written a kafka streaming application in java which reads from one topic. Does some stateless transformations on individual messages and produces it to another topic using Kafka Streams Java API. Can anyone help me how to do performance testing for this application. I want to find the at what rate we are consuming and transforming and producing?

Comment: You can access JMX metrics to get throughput numbers: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/monitoring.html

Comment: In case you want to send the metrics to an external systems you can do that by implementing `org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.MetricsReporter` similarly to how it's done [here](https://github.com/apakulov/kafka-graphite/blob/master/kafka-graphite-clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/metrics/GraphiteReporter.java).